# Retrieving the first file of a directory based on an extension using Java

Tags: java

I have a directory that is plenty of files. What I'm trying to do is return the first xml file I encounter. What I did is put all the files in File[], however that may not be the best solution to retrieve the first xml file, performance wise speaking. Any help?

```
 public String finder( String dirName){
        File dir = new File(dirName);
        File[] fList = dir.listFiles();

        return "";

    }
```

Comment: does the below answer work for you?

Comment: Worked for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a [FilenameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) it will be :

```
public String finder( String dirName)
{
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    if ( dir.isDirectory() )
    {

        String[] list = dir.list(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f, String s ) 
            {
                return s.endsWith(".xml");
            }

       });

        if ( list.length > 0 )
        {
            return list[0];
        }
    }

    return "";

}
```